# Display data with ajax datatable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatable

I've been stuck with this issue for a whole day, well basically I have a table and I need to send data `multidimensional array $list` through datatable with ajax so that I can json encode it and send it back to display:

```
$('#table_test').dataTable( {
    "bProcessing": false,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "ajax.php",
    "sAjaxDataProp": "data",
    "fnServerData" : function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            "dataType" : "json",
            "type" : "POST",
            "url" : sSource,
            "data" : aoData,
            "success" : function(data) {
               fnCallback(data);
            }
        });
    },
    "aoColumns": [
        { "mData": "thumbnail" },
        { "mData": "title" },
        { "mData": "category" },
        { "mData": "price" },
        { "mData": "date_post" },
        { "mData": "actions" }]
});
```

ajax.php (as for testing)

```
<?php

    $array = array(
        "aaData" => array(
            array(
                'thumbnail' => "1",
                'title' => "1",
                'category' => "1",
                'price' => "1",
                'date_post' => "1",
                'actions' => "ONE"
            ),
            array(
                'thumbnail' => "1",
                'title' => "2",
                'category' => "2",
                'price' => "2",
                'date_post' => "2",
                'actions' => "TWO"
            ),
            array(
                'thumbnail' => "3",
                'title' => "3",
                'category' => "3",
                'price' => "3",
                'date_post' => "3",
                'actions' => "THREE"
            ),
        )
    );

    echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

Here's the tabel that I want to populate data with :

```
<table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' border='0' class='datatable table table-striped table-bordered' id='table_test' >

</table>
```

Any help with this? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

just a thought, have you tried to change mData string to aaData in aoColumns like this?

```
 },
"aoColumns": [
    { "aaData": "thumbnail" },
    { "aaData": "title" },
    { "aaData": "category" },
    { "aaData": "price" },
    { "aaData": "date_post" },
    { "aaData": "actions" }]
```

});